# ¿Cómo insertar un sub-menu dentro de otro sub-menu?

Tags: html, navbar

Necesito incluir un sub-menú dentro de un sub-menú en mi sitio web. Intenté agregar un **UL** con el sub-menú que quiero que se muestre en la opción de #CIUDADES, antes de cerrar su **LI**, pero no se muestra en la pantalla.
¿Debo modificar algo en el CSS para que se visualice? La verdad es que no tengo mucha idea de todo esto, estoy aprendiendo a prueba y error modificando la plantilla de blogger.

```html
<ul class='topmenu1 megamenu' id='megamenuid'>
    <li><a href='/'>Inicio</a></li>
    <li>
        <a class='menu-target' href='#'>Megamenu</a>
        <ul class='ulmenu'>
            <li><a href='https://videoplay-oddthemes.blogspot.in/search/label/Lifestyle'>Lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href='https://videoplay-oddthemes.blogspot.in/search/label/Fashion'>Fashion</a></li>
            <li><a href='https://videoplay-oddthemes.blogspot.in/search/label/Beauty'>Beauty</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>URBANO</a>
            <ul class='singlemenu'>
                <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/urbanismo?max-results=1000'>Urbanismo</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/?q=label:paisaje|label:parques?max-results=1000'>Paisaje</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/label/espacio%20público?max-results=1000'>espacio público</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/label/ciudades%20del%20mundo?max-results=1000'>#ciudades</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/label/historia?max-results=1000'>Historia</a></li>
            <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/label/documentales?max-results=900'>Documentales</a></li>
            <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/label/360?max-results=1000'>360°</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href='#'>Otros</a>
                <ul class='singlemenu'>
                    <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/imaginarios?max-results=1000'>Imaginarios</a></li>
                    <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/entrevistas?max-results=1000'>Entrevistas</a></li>
                    <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/search/label/peliculas?max-results=1000'>Películas</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href='https://www.arquifilm.com/p/autores.html'>Autores</a></li>
            </li>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Este es el CSS de los elementos en cuestión. Creo que está todo, espero no falte nada

```css
#menu{
background: #e0e0e0;
color: #999;
height: 44px;
z-index:9;
width:1200px;
margin:0 auto;
border-bottom: 2px solid #BBB;
}
#menu ul,#menu li{margin:0 auto;padding:0 0;list-style:none}
#menu ul{height:50px;width:1180px}
#menu li{float:left;display:inline;position:relative;font:$(body.font);
text-transform: uppercase;}
#menu a{display: block;
line-height: 44px;
padding: 0 19.5px;
text-decoration: none;
color: $(linkcolor);
}
#menu li a:hover{

background: #C8C8C8;
}
li.home a{background:#C8C8C8;}

#menu label{font:bold 30px Lato;display:none;width:35px;height:36px;line-height:36px;text-align:center}
#menu label span{font-size:16px;position:absolute;left:35px}
#menu ul.menus{
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
width: 190px;
background: #c8c8c8;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}
#menu ul.menus li{
display: block;
width: 100%;
font:bold 12px Lato;
text-transform: none;
text-shadow: none;
}
#menu ul.menus a{
color: $(linkcolor);
line-height: 35px;
}
#menu li:hover ul.menus{display:block}
#menu ul.menus a:hover{
background: #B7B7B7;
color: $(hovercolor);
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
#menu{position:relative}
#menu ul{background:#111;position:absolute;top:100%;right:0;left:0;z-index:3;height:auto;display:none}
#menu ul.menus{width:100%;position:static;padding-left:20px}
#menu li{display:block;float:none;width:auto; font:normal 0.8em Lato;}



.topbar.stick-me.sticking {
display: block;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 99999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
-o-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
margin: 0;
max-width: 100%;
height: 51px;
}


.topmenu1 i.fa {
    color: #111;
}
.ot-top-menu li > div:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 8px;
 background: transparent; 
}
.ot-top-menu li > div:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 24px;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.ot-top-menu li:hover > div {
 left: 0;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.ot-top-menu .right {
 float: none;
 border-right-width: 0;
 border-left-width: 1px;
}
.ot-top-menu .right > div {
 -o-transform-origin-x: 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin-x: 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin-x: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
.ot-top-menu .right:hover > div {
 right: 0;
 left: auto;
}
.ot-top-menu .right:hover > div:before {
 right: 24px;
 left: auto;
}
.ot-top-menu .switcher {
 display: none;
}


/**/
/* level 2+ */
/**/
.ot-top-menu li li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 border-width: 0;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 line-height: 21px;
 white-space: normal;
}
.ot-top-menu li li:first-child {
 border-top: 0;
}
.ot-top-menu li li a {
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.ot-top-menu li li &gt; div {
 top: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}
.ot-top-menu li li > div:after {
 top: 0;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: auto;
 left: auto;
 width: 8px;
 height: 100%;
}
.ot-top-menu li li > div:before {
 top: 22px;
 right: 100%;
 bottom: auto;
 left: auto;
 border-top: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
.ot-top-menu li li:hover > div {
 left: 100%;
}
.ot-top-menu .right li > div {
 margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 -o-transform-origin-x: 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin-x: 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin-x: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
.ot-top-menu .right li > div:after {
 right: auto;
 left: 100%;
}
.ot-top-menu .right li > div:before {
 right: auto;
 left: 100%;
 border-right: none;
 border-left: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.ot-top-menu .right li:hover > div {
 right: 100%;
 left: auto;
}



 .ot-top-menu li ul{
  width: 180px;
position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 100%;
  left: -9999px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
visibility:hidden;

  transform: translateY(-10px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: transform 250ms, opacity 200ms;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms, opacity 200ms;
}
```

Comment: Me parece que tenés mal cerrados los `<li>`. Después de cerrar el `<ul class="ulmenu">` abrís un `<li>`, pero antes deberías cerrar el `<li>` superior. Veo eso después de cada `</ul>`. Ahora tenés `<li>` adentro de `<li>`, eso no es correcto, deberían estar dentro de un `<ul>`.

Comment: Sería genial si también adjuntas el CSS de tu proyecto para poder entender mejor

Comment: Hola @azeós, gracias por tu respuesta! Corregí eso del LI que me decías. ¿No puedo poner un LI dentro de otro LI? Entonces cómo podría hacer para que se desprendan del LI "URBANISMO" otras opciones de menú?

Comment: El `<li>` tiene que estar dentro de un `<ul>`, cosa que hiciste y está bien. Pero después de cerrar algunos `<ul>` abrís directamente un `<li>` sin cerrar el anterior, ahí te estaría quedando un `<li>` dentro de otro `<li>`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Intente correr el menu pero el codigo de CSS no coincide con los selectores que tienes: NO veo en la construccion del menu #menu,  label, .menus, .topbar.stick-me.sticking, i.fa, .ot-top-menu  Otra cosa que veo CSS no trabaja con variables solo los prepocesadores: esto en el codigo no esta funcionando $(body.font).